# Make `re-search-forward` return string with Korean characters

Tags: character-encoding

I am trying to implement a web scraper that does the following:

1. Make a request to https://m.weather.naver.com/,
2. Get interesting pieces of information (regarding today's weather), then
3. Organize them nicely into a new org-buffer.

So far, I have this piece of code (credit: http://teaching.sociology.ul.ie/bhalpin/wordpress/?p=580):

```lisp
;;; scrape_weather.el ---  -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

(defun get-weather-page ()
  "get the title text of Naver Weather"
  (set-buffer (url-retrieve-synchronously "https://m.weather.naver.com")) ; set this buffer to current buffer
  (re-search-forward "<title>\\(.+\\)</title>")                           ; re-search for pattern
  (match-string 1))                                                       ; return the first parens in regexp


(defvar *str* (get-weather-page))

;; *str* evals to "\263\327\300\314\271\366 \263\257\276\276".. is there any way I can encode it back to Korean?

;;; scrape_weather.el ends here
```

For debugging purposes, I evaluated the variable `*str*` and got weird sequences of hex codes. That must be `네이버 날씨`, but I'm sure that the decoding of Korean characters got broken after the execution of `re-search-forward`.

Is there any way I can correct the decoding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to handle non-ASCII characters, you need turn on multibyte via `(set-buffer-multibyte t)` (see also [(elisp) Selecting a Representation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Selecting-a-Representation.html)), e.g.,

```
(with-current-buffer (url-retrieve-synchronously
                      "https://m.weather.naver.com")
  (set-buffer-multibyte t)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (re-search-forward "<title>\\(.+\\)</title>")
  (match-string 1))
;; => "네이버 날씨"
```

Emacs uses multibyte mode by default, e.g.,

```
(with-temp-buffer
  enable-multibyte-characters)
;; => t
```

however `url-retrieve-synchronously` turns it off, hence you need to turn it on according to you needs.

> For debugging purposes

here is another way to debug which is more intuitive, eval this code

```
(display-buffer
 (url-retrieve-synchronously
  "https://m.weather.naver.com"))
```

you will see some characters in octal format, and after `M-x toggle-enable-multibyte-characters`, you'll see the actual characters.

Comment: I ended up selecting `string-as-multibyte` for my use case. Thanks for your guidance.